# What is the probability that sum of balls in any subset of a group is divisible by 3?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The question -
There are 2 types of containers containing either 1 or 2 balls.
The number of containers with  1 ball is a and with 2 balls is b.
For any given a, b pair, what is the probability that sum of number of balls in any any random subset of containers is divisible by 3, a subset can be empty set or full set also?

I have been trying to solve this for a long time, initially the question has 3 containers one with 0 balls also, I was able to reduce it to this. I also get the intuition that in any subset has difference between number of 2 balls and number of 1 balls divisible by 3 then the whole subset sum is divisible by 3.

But unfortunately I am not able to proceed from here, can any maths wizard please help?

Comment: Wondering if it is like the number of integer solutions to $(2x + y)=3k$, $k\in{1,2,3,\ldots}$.

Comment: There is a trivial open formula using binomials, maybe there is then some binomial identity to convert it intoa closed one.

Comment: @Quasar yes, but here additional constraints are there on x and y, x<=b y<=a. I know the solution to the problem x1 + x2 + x3 = 3  with xi>=0, but not sure how to apply that with the constraints given in question